Access elastic data from a specific index from jaeger
I have created an index on elastic to store our spans and then trying to access them from jaeger.
I have run the below command command to run a jaeger image to expose 16686 and elastic as the storage with an idex prefix but I dont see anything on jaeger, Am i using the rite options?
export SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch 
export ES_SERVER_URLS=elasticsearch.com:9200 
export ES_INDEX_PREFIX=otel 
podman run -d --name jaeger_query -p 16686:16686 -e SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE -e ES_SERVER_URLS -e ES_INDEX_PREFIX localhost/jaeger:jaegerquery

I can access the jaeger UI but I dont see any spans

Jaeger prefers to name its own indexes, and it will manage the storage there unless you make other changes. You also will need to change the ingestion side, you are only showing the query side.
--es.server-urls=http://elasticsearch:9200 --span-storage.type=elasticsearch is how this should be formatted. If you want to use a specific index it should use : --es.index-prefix but this will just add it before -jaeger so for example from the docs : "production" would use the production-jaeger index.
https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.56/cli/#jaeger-query-elasticsearch

I'm just using jaeger query to view the traces, the data is sent to elastic by an Otel collector.

That will not work, the formats of Jaeger are different than the otel exporter, please see the docs.
